# Why m i getting empty data in Json format after creating Api views using class based Api, How can i show the data i have inserted in admin panel?

Tags: api, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-class-based-views

[This is the output m getting after hitting url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU0pP.png)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Student
from .serializers import StudentSerializer
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status


class StudentAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk = None, format=None ):
        id = pk
        if id is not None:
            stu = Student.objects.get(id = id)
            serializer = StudentSerializer(stu)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        
        stu = Student.objects.all()
        serializer = StudentSerializer(stu, many= True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def post(self, request, format= None):
        serializer = StudentSerializer(data= request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'msg': 'Data Created'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    
    def put(self, request, pk, format= None):
        id = pk
        stu = Student.objects.get(pk = id)
        serializer = StudentSerializer(stu, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'msg':'Complete Data Updated!'})
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
      
    def patch(self, request, pk, format = None):
        id = pk
        stu = Student.objects.get(pk = id)
        serializer = StudentSerializer(stu, data = request.data, partial= True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'msg':'Partial data Updated'})
        return Response(serializer.errors)
    
    def delete(self, request, pk, format= None):
        id = pk
        stu = Student.objects.get(pk=id)
        stu.delete()
        return Response({'msg':'Data Deleted!'})
```

Here I have created views using class Based api views and mentioned all the http request, But as a response i am not getting the json data that i have posted in django_admin panel after creating superuser.